# JDBC : below SQL doesn't return any row in jboss, while works fine in local

Tags: oracle, jdbc, openshift, driver, jboss7.x

Below query doesn't work (written in a webapp) in jboss while works in websphere - same WAR

Select 1 from customers where customerID=?

Using prepared statement and then execute query

DB type : oracle

My analysis
1. Ensured Database connection details are correct

2. Debugged in local for the given input, db connection and it works as expected. - returns expected result
3. Ran query directly in the database, ensured data is present.
4. Don't have access to jboss console, so not sure which driver is being used.

What could be the reason? Has anyone faced this issue before ? FYI the code is quite old and works fine IN WAS 7 oracle driver 18.

Comment: I would check the datatype used for the "?" variable and make sure it matches the datatype of the customer id in the table.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Datatype is also valid, as I said the application works fine in websphere and has been working since long, facing issue when i deployed in jboss

Comment: Are you looking at the same database, is the data you are viewing locally actually committed? Please post a [mre].